# Who is the mysterious man in the bowling alley in Fargo S03E08 and what is his role?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, fargo-tv

In the *Fargo* TV series S03E08, we see that Nikki and Mr. Wrench sneak into a bowling alley after the deathly chase between them and Yuri Gurka. Sitting in the bar, there's a mysterious man in a suit. He is the same man who we saw in S03E03 talking to Gloria on her trip to find out about Ennis's life.

I got confused about his actions when he helped Nikki by giving her his car key, and more interestingly, he recognized Yuri Gurka and even knew about his roots.

Who is that man? Are we watching a symbolic scene in which he is helping and punishing the protagonist and antagonist in a godly manner?

Comment: Why the close votes please?  I mean seriously?  If you have not seen this episode then please don't downvote because you do not understand the question.  If you have seen the episode please enlighten me as to why this is an invalid or unfocused question?

Comment: "who is" and "what is his role" are certainly intertwined questions that can reasonably answered together.

Comment: I voted to close because it's a bit unfocused. There's at least three questions here; Who is he? What is he doing in this scene? What is his role in general? You're not wrong that an answer to one might be an answer to all, but they also might not be.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FiNL7jMyJX4 - Who is the green man with the gun? What is he doing in this scene? What is his role in general?

Comment: This character appears in the one scene, impacts the plot significantly, and can reasonably be explained as a divine/supernatural intervention or hallucination.  The question is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Valorum Your example of Greedo seems to support leaving the question open but your comment seems to support closing the question. Regarding Greedo, he’s a bounty hunter chasing Han Solo because Han owes money to a gangster. This helps us understand that Han is in a somewhat desperate situation when we meet him and he’s not a pure Good Guy, but he is helping the main character for now. See? Not at all too broad a question.

Comment: It's impossible to tell whether it was real or symbolic, because every season of the show has something like that, like UFO in the season 2. I guess it's a nod to Coen brothers movies, which also has this semi-surreal ambiguity.